# Javascript array items == "undefined" in Google Maps function

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, google-maps

Hello
I'm looping over a JSON object and creating a new map marker for each item. After the marker is created, I push it to an array (*var markers*) for future manipulation. Problem is, when I try to access the array items (eg: *console.log(markers[3])*), I am given an "undefined" value.

Relevant code below:

```
var map;
var markers = [];
var activeFilters = [];

function initializeMap() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng( 51.506873, -0.125141);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 14,
        center: myLatlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        disableDefaultUI: true
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("location_map"), myOptions);


    $.getJSON('../js/hotspots.json', function(data) {
        var hotspots = data.scenes[0].hotspots;
        $.each(hotspots, function(i) {

            var lat = hotspots[i].latitude;
            var lon = hotspots[i].longitude;
            var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lon);

            var cat = hotspots[i].hotspottype;
            var weburl = hotspots[i].weburl;

            var marker = addMarker(point,cat,weburl);
        });

    });


}

function addMarker(point, cat, weburl) {
    var markerUrl = weburl;
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: point,
        map: map
    });

    marker.category = cat;
    markers.push(marker);
};

initializeMap();
console.log(markers[3]);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: seems like you are attempting to access the markers[3] before it's pushed onto the global array.  before .getJSON callback function is executed.

Comment: kjy112, of course! I've been staring at this for a while, but never noticed that this all needs to happen inside the callback. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get json runs asynchronously. try this:

```
$.getJSON('../js/hotspots.json', function(data) {
    var hotspots = data.scenes[0].hotspots;
    $.each(hotspots, function(i) {
        var lat = hotspots[i].latitude;
        var lon = hotspots[i].longitude;
        var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lon);
        var cat = hotspots[i].hotspottype;
        var weburl = hotspots[i].weburl;
        var marker = addMarker(point,cat,weburl);
    });
    console.log(markers);
});
```

Comment: thanks - that's what the problem was (as mentioned by kjy112). Thank you both for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to

```
console.log(markers[0]);
```

because looking at your code, there is just one element in `markers` array.

If you will put into that array 4 elements, then using `markers[3]` you will access fourth element.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
initializeMap();
setTimeout(function(){
    console.log(markers[3]);
}, 10000);
```